# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'sa'.'

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm working on my coding course, and during the SQL section, it was time to run the code. I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'sa'

The error line is marked in the code.

```
namespace Zoo_With_SQL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Zoo_With_SQL.Properties.Settings.MaydayDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            ShowZoos();
        }

        private void ShowZoos()
        {
            string query = "select * from Zoo";

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);

            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                DataTable zooTable = new DataTable();

                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(zooTable); // Error here!

                // What should be shown
                ZooList.DisplayMemberPath = "Location";
                // Value when selected
                ZooList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
                // The reference to use
                ZooList.ItemsSource = zooTable.DefaultView;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've already done the heavily-reccomended Server Authenication type changing.

Comment: check your sa credentials

Comment: Please share connection string

Comment: If you're learning: one lesson is to **NEVER** use the `sa` account in any of your production code - just don't do it; that user has waaaaaaay too many permission and if the connection string with your `sa` password leaks out, your SQL Server can be hijacked and any data on it is gone or deleted or open to manipulation. **Don't use `sa`** - not from code - period.

Comment: Update your question with connection string by masking sensitive details.

Answer (score 4):

This could be a reason for receiving this error, if your SQL Server has not been configured to use Mixed mode authentication, it doesn't actually tell you that this is not enabled!. Make sure that you have the **Mixed-Mode authentication** enabled and here is how to enable it.

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio and right-click on Server Node and select Properties.
   [image]
2. Now go to Security Tab and go to Server Authentical Area. Select SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.

   [image]
3. Click **OK** to close the Server Properties window.
4. Right-click the SQL instance and choose **Restart**.
5. Click **Yes** to restart the SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your connection string. Please ensure that SQL server is running on mixed mode authentication.

**Mixed mode authentication:**
Go to Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server > Enterprise Manager
Right-click the SQL Server instance name > Select Properties from the context menu > Select Security node in left navigation bar
Under Authentication section, select SQL Server and Windows Authentication
Note: The server must be stopped and re-started before this will take effect

**Standard connection string:**

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

**Connection string for named instance:**

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution

Step 1

Create a new user for sql, dont use windwos auth

I used this tut

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfuK0V1tlrA&t=1s

Step 2

Add your connection string with your new creds

"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=qwerty;**TrustServerCertificate=true**"
}