# Remote connection to SQL Server with Windows security and impersonation

Tags: sql-server, security, iis, database-connection, impersonation

I want to tune Windows login to dbmail (for sending attachment), first step is simple open connection to SQL Server where the dbmail configuration is stored.

I have created an account in Windows named `dbmail`, and then I created a SQL login for it:

```
 CREATE LOGIN [QQQQQQQ\dbmail] FROM WINDOWS
```

I set needed permission for this SQL login to `(SqlAdministrator)`.

[Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFsew.png)

Then I try to connect to SQL with this connection string:

```
ATT_tds_STRING = "Data Source=localhost; Database=YYYYY; uid=QQQQQQQQ\dbmail; pwd=xxxxxxxxxxxx; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

My function placed inside COM-object

```
Public Function DbMailSendMail(CN As String, DbMailProfileName As String, SmSender As String, SmRecptLst As String, SmCCLst As String, SmBCCLst As String, SmSubject As String, SmMsg As String, SmAttach As String) As String Implements IDbMail.DbMailSendMail
    Dim SQLCN As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(CN)
    SQLCN.Open()
    Try
        Dim CMD As New SqlClient.SqlCommand($"EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @body_format = 'HTML', " &
        ....
```

When I call my function from ASP page

```
   Dim Mailer1, Res1
   Set Mailer1 = Server.CreateObject("TDS.DbMail")
   Res1 = Mailer1.DbMailSendMail (ATT_tds_STRING, "ZZZZZZZ", "", Request.Form("Mailto"), "", "", Request.Form("title"), Request.Form("body"), "C:\www\tdsv5\Images\BeOS_Help.gif")
```

Unfortunately I get a strange result

> .Net SqlClient Data Provider error '80131904'
> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

I expect Windows authentication in `SqlClient.SqlConnection(CN)` with login QQQQQQQ\dbmail (because I use exactly Windows login and SSPI security), however Windows appears to be using IIS impersonation account NT AUTHORITY\IUSR to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: The only way to do this is with impersonation of the Windows login, which is a mess and a half. Honestly you should either change the Windows user for the IIS app pool to `dbmail` or just create a (Windows Auth) login on SQL Server for `IUSR`. There is no way to explicitly specify a Windows username and password as part of the connection string, it will always use the currently logged in (or impersonated) user

Comment: You can try the solution in this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66148440/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user-sa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66148440/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user-sa).

Answer (score 0):

According advice @Charlieface, I have created login

```
 CREATE LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\IUSR] FROM WINDOWS
```

and set up to this login special roles in MSDB

[DatabasemailUserRole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D12sv.png)

After that all working fine. Connection string is

```
 ATT_tds_STRING = "Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI"
```